# Simplex method in matrix form with the big $M$ method?

Tags: simplex

If I have one constraint $3_{x1}+2_{x2}=18$ in a maximize problem 
you need to fulfil $AX\le b$
what should I do to fit the condition ?
What I think is: 
$3_{x1}+2_{x2}\le 18$ and 
$3_{x1}+2_{x2}\ge 18$ becomes $-3_{x1}-2_{x2}\le -18.$
In tableau form we can use the big $M$ method to fix this but in matrix form this is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know is the number of decision variables and number of constraints involved in your problem. I don't see any reason to split equality equations into two inequalities. One can directly add an artificial variable in the equality constraint $3x_1+2x_2=18$ and proceed with Big M or Two Phase method to obtain the solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: that's mean the equality constraint in matrix form is not necessary to add any artificial variables U may do this with two-phase method and Big M method?